# How to style PrimeNg properly in Angular app

Tags: css, angular, sass, primeng

I am trying to change the style of PrimeNg accordion in my component: https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/accordion Simple changes, like font-style, color changes... etc. The page says I can pass a style with *styleClass*. That does not work for me.

In my component I could remove the shadow the following way:

```
::ng-deep .p-accordion .p-accordion-header:not(.p-disabled) .p-accordion-header-link:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

As I know its not recommended to use ng-deep. Without the ng-deep nothing happens unless I put the CSS into a "global" CSS file. But then it's not just changed in my own component.

Also the CSS selector is crazy long, obviously I copied from the inspector.

What is the right way to set the style of a PrimeNg element?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no "clean" way to change the styles of a child component from a parent component. A third option is (beside ng-deep and global css file) turning off the view encapsulation at the parent component. Therefore `ViewEncapsulation.None` should be used, [documentation can be found here](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation).
In this case the parent component can overwrite styles of a child component, so you can remove the shadow in the PrimeNg element from the parent this way.

Comment: I guess that makes it global, the CSS itself just in a component file.
I wonder how styleClass should be used...